# file download page - things that need to be considered

Tags: php, asp.net, ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc, django

everytime I download something from some website, I get redirect to a different page than it says that ***"the download will start in 5 seconds, or click this link"***

I'm also building a site now where authenticated users should be able to download some files

I would like to know **what are things that need to be considered when building a download page ?**

(probably something like anti-bots that would download the same file for 100 times etc.)

Comment: A bot won't be able to download anything from you if your downloads are behind a login page so I don't think that's an issue

Comment: @pastylegs bot might login and download the file 1000 times, also why is there everywhere a separate page where the user has to wait for the download for 5 seconds

Comment: @ChuckNorris I think you have to wait for the download for 5 seconds so they can show you ads

Comment: Why are you listing so many programming languages? And what are you aiming for? Your question is pretty broad, is this only about bots? Can you specify what a bot is? What about download managers? Do you want to support download managers? Do you want to display ads/notices, and those must be read/accepted/clicked before downloading? The 100 times download limit, across which time-span does this apply?

Comment: @hakre I'm listing most popular web frameworks, I'm aiming for a secure "bad guy proof" download page

Comment: Please specify the concrete actions of "bad guy" of which "bad guy proof" needs to be able to deal with.

Comment: @hakre I don't know, that's the whole point, "things that need to be considered"

Comment: @Chuck Norris: Well, take your webserver offline, and you are 100% bad guy safe. Everything else won't do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how many users controls do you want to add...

1) You can add a captcha control for every download attempt

2) You can "show" it only when some user (identified by IP) download N files, simply get the IP and add into a database (for history pourpose) with date time, if a user try to download another (or the same) file in less than X time you can show a captcha or block the download.

3) considering what you wrote in the answer I suppose that you know how to create a downloader.php that send the file itself and not the direct link to the file.

Best way I know to protect a file from unauthorized access/download is to put it into a folder not reachable from web, using php to load it and let the user download, or copy it to a temporary directory accessible from web and give the user the tmp link (created dinamically).

In the second case you need to clean the tmp directory once in a while